# How can I give menu item id="active", if its subpage in a drop-down menu is open? PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

If a menu item has sub-pages, main page itself is not clickable - only its sub-pages are.
My question is, how can i add id="active" to menu item in case its sub-page is open?

I am afraid the solution can't be achieved with URL, because the URL for subpages is: `subpage.php?id=5` and in the database, `pages` and `subpages` tables have the same `page_id`.

So using `(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == 'subpage.php?id='.$page['page_id'])` gives a wrong result..
It makes items active such as `$subpage['subpage_id'] = $page['page_id']` but I need a result like this: `$subpage['page_id'] = $page['page_id']`..

How can I achieve that without the need of URL?

Tables:
`pages = page_id (AI, primary), page_name;
subpages = subpage_id (AI, primary), page_id, subpage_name;`

My subpages.php file:

```
<?php
include_once('classes.php');

$page = new Page;
$subpage = new Subpage;

$pages = $page->fetch_all();
$subpages = $subpage->fetch_all();
?>

<div class="sidenav">

<?php foreach ($pages as $page) { ?>

    <button class="dropdown-btn"
    <?php foreach ($subpages as $subpage) {
//DOWN HERE IS THE PROBLEM!
        if ($subpage['subpage_id'].$page['page_id']) {
            echo('id="active" ');
        } }?> >
        <?php echo $page['page_name']; ?>
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>    

//DOWN HERE I MAKE SUB-PAGES ACTIVE
<div class="dropdown-container">
    <?php foreach ($childpages as $childpage): ?>
        <a 
        <?php 
        if (basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == 'subpage.php?id='.$subpage['subpage_id'].'') {
            echo('id="active-sub" ');
        }
        ?>
        href="subpage.php?id=<?php echo $childpage['subpage_id']; ?>">
            <?php echo $childpage['subpage_name']; ?>
        </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<?php } ?>

</div>
```

classes.php file:

```
class Page {
    public function fetch_all(){
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pages");
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }    
public function fetch_data($page_id) {
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_id = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $page_id);
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetch();
    }
}

class Subpage {
    public function fetch_all(){
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM subpages");
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
public function fetch_data($subpage_id) {
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM subpages WHERE subpage_id = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $subpage_id);
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetch();
    }
}
```

Right now, I get all pages 'active' when any sub-pages is open..

Summary:

I need a result like this: `$subpage['page_id'] = $page['page_id']`.
How can I achieve that without the need of URL?

Comment: Please add the table structure for pages and subpages.

Comment: I updated my code.

Comment: This might work: `if ($subpage['page_id'] == $page['page_id']) {`

Comment: sadly, this makes all the pages active at once, no matter what sub-page is open :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this, i added the id of the current sub-page as a variable::

```
<?php
include_once('classes.php');

$page = new Page;
$subpage = new Subpage;

$pages = $page->fetch_all();
$subpages = $subpage->fetch_all();

$currentSubpageId = intval($_GET['id']),
?>

<div class="sidenav">

<?php foreach ($pages as $page) { ?>

    <button class="dropdown-btn"
    <?php foreach ($subpages as $subpage) {
        if($currentSubpageId == $subpage['subpage_id'] && $subpage['page_id'] == $page['page_id']) 
        {
            echo('id="active" ');
        } 
    }?> >
        <?php echo $page['page_name']; ?>
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>    

//DOWN HERE I MAKE SUB-PAGES ACTIVE
<div class="dropdown-container">
    <?php foreach ($childpages as $childpage): ?>
        <a 
        <?php 
        if (basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == 'subpage.php?id='.$subpage['subpage_id'].'') {
            echo('id="active-sub" ');
        }
        ?>
        href="subpage.php?id=<?php echo $childpage['subpage_id']; ?>">
            <?php echo $childpage['subpage_name']; ?>
        </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<?php } ?>

</div>
```